# C# MSChart add hover Line

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mschart, mousehover

When you click into a mschart a red line appears, is it somehow possible to add this line while hovering over the chart? I would like to make this line visible while hovering and add the result of the hovered datapoint under the line or something like that. So far I only found out about tooltip and was able to use it and show values of datapoint while hovering over it.
If you dont know about what line I'm talking:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle `MouseHover` event of the chart and get the data point and then set the cursor position `SetCursorPosition`:

```
private void chart1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var p = chart1.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SetCursorPixelPosition(p, true);
}
```

You also need to handle `MouseMove` and call protected `ResetMouseEventArgs` method of the control to raise `MouseHover` as expected:

```
private void chart1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var ResetMouseEventArgs= 
        chart1.GetType().GetMethod("ResetMouseEventArgs",
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    ResetMouseEventArgs.Invoke(chart1, null);
}
```

Comment: I changed `MouseHover` a bit.